# How to disable install pig step from aws data pipeline

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

I am creating a data pipeline using EMR Cluster as resource.
As server is creating after bootstrap,
It is executing some step automatically, that are

```
enable debugging,
Install Hive
Install Pig
install Task runner
```

Everthing is okey.

But I want to remove the step Install pig from that.
is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can remove any of those steps, since datapipeline installs those for you. Is there any reason you want to remove the steps?

Comment: reson is it is installing latest pig version automatically but ami doesn't support so job fails

Comment: Is this a specific ami you are using or is this the default ami that datapipeline provides? You can specify the amiId in the emrCluster fields to specify a newer ami that supports the latest pig version

Comment: I am using latest as ami version

Comment: Can you recheck the AMI Id provided. I tried running a pig activity on emr cluster with both "latest" as amiid and leaving the ami id unspecified and letting datapipeline decide the ami for me. Both the time the step that installs pig completed fine.
AMI 2.4.2 - latest - Install Pig step succeeded
AMI 2.2.4 - datapipeline selected this AMI when I left the ami version unspecified. - Install Pig step succeeded
Is install pig step failure the correct symptom of your failure?

Comment: This is the actuall error in "sysout:>>"ERROR Hadoop version 0.20.205 does not support pig version 0.11.1.1", Soory! for it was not ami , it was hadoop that cause the issue

Comment: You can specify the hadoop version with the hadoop version field as shown in the  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emrcluster.html example

Comment: I am using hive, that also should be compatible with hadoop version. i am not using pig, that also take around one min in step. so i just want to remove unnecessary step.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Just to make clear here "latest" in the amiVersion is bounded by the hadoopVersion field. As well, the "latest" usage is outdated and only applies to Hadoop 1 and earlier on EMR.  With Hadoop 2.x it is best practice to forgo hadoopVersion field and just set amiVersion.

Answer (score -1):

This answer considers the info about the error in the comments.

It appears you are getting a very old Hadoop version installed. Look at the hadoopVersion field defined in on the EmrCluster object, it likely says "0.20".   I would say remove this field and replace it with amiVersion (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emrcluster.html). Select a more recent version as listed at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html.